# SQLite  метод  удаления  строк  с  определенным  значением  поля

Tags: sqlite3, android, java

Есть  метод

```
public int delete(String namedell){
    int col;
    return col = getWritableDatabase().delete("tiemtable", "numdet" + "=" + namedell, null);
}
```

Получаю  партянку:

> 05-07 13:06:56.916:
> E/AndroidRuntime(23407):
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
> near ".182": syntax error (code 1): ,
> while compiling: DELETE FROM tiemtable
> WHERE numdet=14016.45.182

Вижу, что  ругается  на  синтаксис,  но  не  могу  понять  в  чем именно  проблема.

Заранее  спасибо  за  ответы.

Comment: экранируйте numdet, он его пытается как число распарсить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

так:

```
.getWritableDatabase().delete("tiemtable", "numdet" + "='" + namedell + "'", null);
```

Строку надо брать в кавычки при использовании в SQL выражении

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: что будет если в строке есть кавычка?  
правильно так:

    .getWritableDatabase().delete("tiemtable", "numdet=?",new String[]{namedell});

Answer (score 0):

```
public int delete(String namedell){
        int col;
        return col = getWritableDatabase().delete("tiemtable", "numdet" + "='" + namedell+"'", null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

а

```
"numdet ='" + namedell + "'"
```

не прокатит ? :)